# Error while deploying EAR using Wildfly13.0.0.0

Tags: server, configuration, wildfly

I've upgraded the server from "JBOSS-EAP 6" to "Wildfly 13.0.0.0", I've also set all needed configurations, but when starting to deploy EAR I get the below ERROR. What does it mean?

> MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.subunit."mpaymentapp-ear.ear"."mpaymentapp-imt-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.subunit."mpaymentapp-ear.ear"."mpaymentapp-imt-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL:
>   WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment
>   "mpaymentapp-imt-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment
>   "mpaymentapp-ear.ear"     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.

Comment: There should be some error messages further up in the logs.

Comment: here's other errors in log
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0052: Failed to install component ImtCustomerManagerImpl
Caused by:org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type 'com.cit.mpaymentapp.common.util.FileManagerLocal'

Comment: MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."mpaymentapp-ear.ear#MP": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."mpaymentapp-ear.ear#MP": org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to construct requested dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect

Comment: It looks like you might be including Hibernate in your deployment. If so try removing it.